Clear cache on each iteration - JMeter
Should we clear on each iteration in our load scenario in jmeter
Original time in browser : 5 seconds
When I check Clear cache each iteration: 5 seconds
When I uncheck Clear cache each iteration: 100 milliseconds
Please suggest what should I do while testing (should I clear or not), the stats I shared are for single load

There is no sense in "single load"
The whole idea of performance testing of web applications is simulating real user using the real browser, it assumes:

configuring JMeter to download embedded resources
use HTTP Cache Manager to represent browser cache
use HTTP Cookie Manager to mimic browser cookies storage
use Parallel Controller to simulate AJAX requests

Whether you decide to simulate "new" or "returning" it depends on your workload model, the behaviour can be controller on Thread Group level via "Same user on each iteration" checkbox

Are you representing a new session or a returning user?  Knowing that will inform whether your cache should be clean before starting your iteration
